# Attempt to apply non-function when creating column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to take a column called "F1" and create a new column called "F1.erb" by applying a formula the value in the F1 column. I have tried the following code:

```
data$F1.erb <- data$F1(21.4*log10((4.37/1000)+1))
```

Where "data" is the name of my data frame.

I received the following error message:

Error: attempt to apply non-function

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Did you meant `data$F1 *(`

Comment: Could you describe in "plain mathematical notation" what you want to do, if we assign the name `x` to values of `data$F1`? Basically the way you'd write it out on a plain TI-84 calculator. E. g. " y(x) = x * 21.4 * log10( (4.37/1000) + 1) " - does this describe the formula/function you want to apply? iIf not, could you write the actual formula in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `[` instead of `(`.  The `(` is used mainly as a function or to get codes in a block.  Here, it seems to be interpreted as `data$F1` is some kind of function which it is not.  If we want to multiply then

```
data$F1 *(21.4*log10((4.37/1000)+1))
```